# Tetrahedron orientation

Tags: mesh

I am developing a software that needs to interact with a mesh processing program, using tetrahedral meshes, however I am finding difficulties in this.

The program requires all tetrahedrons to have **right handed orientation**, and this is not the hard part, as given a list of vertices $\{ v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$, I need to check that

$h := ( \; (v_0 - v_1) \times (v_0 - v_2) \;) \cdot (v_0  - v_3) > 0$

In case $h < 0$, any odd permutation will be correct, as $\{ v_0, v_1, v_3, v_2 \}$.

The problem is that, as they told me, the program requires that **all faces are oriented with the right hand rule**.

This requirement puzzles me, and I do not understand it completely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

#### Code

```
class tetrahedron:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        # compute handedness
        c = numpy.cross(vertices[0].coords-vertices[1].coords, vertices[0].coords-vertices[2].coords)
        h = numpy.inner( c, vertices[0].coords-vertices[3].coords )

        # vertex indices with correct right-handed orientation
        if h > 0:
            self.vertices = vertices
        else:
            s = "old h = %f" % (h)
            # swap last two vertices
            self.vertices = [vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[3], vertices[2]]
            vertices = self.vertices
            c = numpy.cross(vertices[0].coords-vertices[1].coords, vertices[0].coords-vertices[2].coords)
            h = numpy.inner( c, vertices[0].coords-vertices[3].coords )
            s = s + " new h = %f" % (h)
            print(s)
```

#### Updated Code

I have updated my code according to the suggestions, but apparently faces are still a problem, the error it gives is

```
Two elements connect to the same side of the shared element face. Coordinates: 12.3669, -61.573, 81.0725
```

My code is now as follows:

```
import numpy

def handedness(vertices):
    c = numpy.cross(vertices[1].coords-vertices[0].coords, \
                    vertices[2].coords-vertices[0].coords)
    h = numpy.inner( c, vertices[3].coords-vertices[0].coords )
    return h

class tetrahedron:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        h = handedness(vertices)

        if h > 0:
            self.vertices = vertices
        else:
            s = "old h = %f" % (h)
            # swap last two vertices
            self.vertices = [vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[3], vertices[2]]
            vertices = self.vertices
            h = handedness(self.vertices)
            s = s + " new h = %f" % (h)
            print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

This refers to the order of vertices within a face. Typically in 3D graphics, faces are wound counterclockwise, so that if you're looking from outside of the tetrahedron/mesh, all the front faces will have their vertices in counterclockwise order. (See [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling#Winding_order) and [here](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/126352/Opinion_Backface_Culling_101.php) for more explanation.) This is a "right-hand rule" in that if the fingers of your right hand curl in the winding direction of the vertices, then your thumb points toward the outside of the mesh.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I ensure that a tet has the right face orientation? I am using the above to check the handedness of a solid (a tet), should I check all faces? So checking for each face $j$, ie, $(-1)^{j}[v_{0},\ldots ,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},\ldots ,v_{n}]$ some property? Is there a closed formula?

Comment: I would need to know more about the program and the context of this requirement. I would expect that given a tet in the correct orientation that it would automatically generate the correct faces. The requirement might refer to some other faces, e.g. the faces of a volume which is being subdivided and filled with tetrahedra, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've included my code for a tet (maybe I am doing something wrong and I don't see it), the software I am interfacing with [is this](https://www.comsol.de/model/comsol-multiphysics-mesh-import-and-export-guide-72351), here is **[the link to the documentation](https://www.comsol.de/model/download/711411/COMSOL_MeshImportExportGuide.pdf)**, where tets are on page 38. I thought my code would be sufficient, but writing a mesh file with vertices and tets will raise an error on faces. Of course a single tet works.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at your tet handedness equation again, I think you have a sign error - the vectors should be like $v_i - v_0$ rather than $v_0 - v_i$. In other words, all the vectors should be based at $v_0$ and pointing toward the other vertices. That's consistent with the tet diagram on page 38, I think.

Comment: Nathan, thank you very much for pointing that out. I've corrected the code but it seems that faces are still a problem. There's something I am missing here, maybe. If you have any idea that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help further with the information available. The error message seems to suggest that the set of tets might be duplicated, or contain overlapping tets reusing the same faces somehow.